# ListView no se ajusta al contenido

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion donde se consulta las tarjetas de credito del cliente y puede visualizar los movimientos de cada una. El problema viene en la actividad donde se crea la lista de los movimientos, que se genera desde una solicitud en Volley, ya que la lista no se ajusta al contenido que se genera. La vista principal es "activity_card.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CardActivity"
    android:background="@color/bg_cards">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Toolbar con el botón "Atrás" -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/fondo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="206dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Movimientos"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/tarjeta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/esquinas"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbarCard"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_cardType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="Tarjeta"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_Card"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView_cardType"
                    app:riv_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
                    app:riv_border_width="1dip"
                    app:riv_corner_radius="15dip"
                    app:riv_mutate_background="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_balance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_black"
                    android:text="$0.00"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_Card" />

                <!--<ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggle_number"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn=""
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView_number" />-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:text="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_Card" />

                <!--<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Ocultar"
        android:textOn="Mostrar"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_cardHolder_Label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:text="PROPIETARIO"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_number" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_cardHolder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="TARJETAHABIENTE"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.118"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView_Card"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_cardHolder_Label" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/caducidad"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView_cardHolder"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_Card">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                        android:text="EXP"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_expire"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                        android:text="01/01"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mov_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Despues esta la vista de "mov_item.xml", donde se dibuja cada elemento de la lista:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mov_logo"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/coin"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mov_type"
                android:text="Tipo"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/mov_logo"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mov_date"
                android:text="Fecha"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/mov_logo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mov_type"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mov_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_black"
                android:text="Monto"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Este es el diseño que me arroja Android Studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el diseño final cuando compilo la aplicacion, aqui se puede ver como los elementos solo se dibujan en una sola linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que es porque en tu item, estas usando MARGIN en vez de PADDINGS. android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"